# How to count views of posts with CakePHP3?

Tags: sql, cakephp, count, controller, sql-update

I am using cakephp 3. In the controller I am using this code:

```
    $conn = ConnectionManager::get('default');
    $stmt = $conn->execute('UPDATE posts SET views = views + 1 WHERE id = '.$id.';');
```

is there a possibility to write this statement "cakephp-like"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a possibility:

```
$posts = TableRegistry::get('Posts');
$query = $posts->query();
$query->update()
    ->set($query->newExpr('views = views + 1'))
    ->where(['id' => $id])
    ->execute();
```

Comment: thanks. that works great when i put "use Cake\ORM\TableRegistry;" into the PostsController. Thanks again